# iPhone Provisioning Files

Tags: iphone, provisioning

Iam  developing an iphone application and currently in the develpoment phase. Since my client need to verify my work I am sending him program builds with provision files. However sometimes he wants to add few UUIDs to existing provision file. What I want to know is does a new provision file works with old builds of my software ? or do I have to send him a new build compiled with the new provision file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work. As long as you're using the same App ID and certificate when creating the profile and the UDIDs that you previously added, everything is fine. You can edit an existing profile and download it again, btw.

The reverse case (new build, old profile) will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to send him a new build with the new provisioning profile if you need to add devices.  Each provisioning profile works **only with the devices assigned to it**, so adding any means replacing your current provisioning profile and rebuilding.  The profile is stored with the binary created by building the app, so it can only be changed before a build.  If you're still having trouble, check the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html).

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not true. The app is being signed with your developer certificate, not the provisioning profile. You don't need to rebuild your app if you create a new profile. As long as the profile matches the distribution cert and app-id that have been used to build the app, it will work even with an old build. I am sure about this, because we just tried it. Created a new profile for an old build and installed both on a new device - works.

Comment: A provisioning profile needs to be installed on a device in order for a device to run an app.  If the provisioning profile cannot be installed, the device cannot run the app.  The provisioning profile must be the same as when the app was built.  I've run into this problem numerous times.

Comment: It must have the same parameters (app id and distrib. cert), but it doesn't have to be the one present at build time. We tried it out, just half an hour ago. It was working 100%. We created a new ad hoc profile for an old app that we did not (!) rebuild. Instead we installed the old build along with the new profile on a device that the app has not been installed on before, and the UDID had never been part of the original profile. We did only install the new profile, not the old one. That is pretty much all I can tell you - maybe your experiences have been related to other code signing issues?

Comment: That is very interesting.  Whenever we have tried to do that we always got an error.  And there haven't been other code signing issues.  Adding the app has always had the "Incorrect provisioning profile" error.

Comment: Hmm.. tricky! I don't know what to add - and of course I don't want to neglect your experiences. Maybe I will repeat the experiment with a new app and under even more precisely controlled conditions, just to make sure. In case you maybe purposely perform a similar test, would you please let me know about your findings? There are so many catches to the whole codesigning process - if I am mistaken in any way I am eager to know...

Comment: I will be more than happy to keep you updated!  I do suspect it may have been the SDK though, as we haven't had any problems with this since we upgraded to 3.2.4 and 3.2.5. but who knows what will happen (especially with how buggy 3.2.5 is!)

Comment: My experience is like this , at first as Toastor said my old builds worked with new provision files and now  I have to rebuild the app with the new provision get it working. What I noticed  in project Settings is  when ever I insert a new provision , the old one does not get replaced with new one.There's new entry for the each provision I put. As I could remembee, at first when ever I put a new one the old one disappeared and only the new one was availble. I am usign 3.1.3